# Does Spy Kit have any use outside of a Conspiracy Draft?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Both flavor-wise and mechanically, [Spy Kit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpy%20Kit%5d) is designed to work with hidden agendas from Conspiracy such as [Adriana's Valor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAdriana%27s%5d%2b%5bValor%5d).  You can use Spy Kit outside a Conspiracy Draft, but you can't use the eponymous conspiracy card types.

The obvious thing to do with it would have been to create legendary name conflicts via [Leyline of Singularity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLeyline%20of%20Singularity%5d), but the legend rule is now player specific, and spy kit is an equipment, so you can't equip it to an opponent's creature (easily).

Given all that, can you do anything with Spy Kit outside of a Conspiracy Draft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two general categories of things you can do with it.

First, you can use it to power up cards that look for other permanents with a particular name.  [Biovisionary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBiovisionary%5d) is probably the strongest example here.  Here are a few more examples: [Cleric of the Forward Order](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCleric%20of%20the%20Forward%20Order%5d), [Shadowborn Apostle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShadowborn%20Apostle%5d), and [Urborg Panther](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUrborg%20Panther%5d).

Second, you can use it to exploit cards that care about things with the "same name".  This works because Conspiracy: Take the Crown added the following rule to Magic:

> 201.2b If an object has more than one name, it has the same name as another object if there are one or more names that both objects have in common.

The best use of this I can think of is to get Spy Kit on an opponent's non-black creature (such as via [Donate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDonate%5d) or [Act of Treason](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAct%20of%20Treason%5d)) and then target that creature with [Eradicate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEradicate%5d), which will exile all non-legendary creatures from their hand, library, and graveyard, which is absolutely devastating to many decks.  You can also use this for slightly less grand effects, such as exiling all non-legendary non-token creatures with [Detention Sphere](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDetention%20Sphere%5d) or bouncing them with [Echoing Truth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEchoing%20Truth%5d).  If all your creatures are legendary, these can be pretty one-sided; you trade one creature (equipped with Spy Kit) for a bunch of theirs.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one card that does something specific when another card named something specific is on the battlefield, [Marauding Maulhorn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarauding%20Maulhorn%5d). Its effect is incredibly minor and probably not worth caring about, but it is an answer to your question.

Comment: I believe this falls under the category of "cards that look for other permanents with a particular name"

Comment: @Zags you're right, I misread and thought all of those examples were looking for other things with the same name as themselves, but I see now that Urborg Panther looks for things with specific names other than Urborg Panther.